# Meteor: Create New Screen in Todos example

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using the todos example from Meteor framework. What API methods render a new page? For example, if I click a link of a record, it should render a new page inside the main frame. I know that SPA is what Meteor has in mind so I'm not sure whether I am using the best approach.

Essentially, what I want is a way for the user to navigate inside a record from a table of rows, and view all it's related data.

Comment: try `page.js` in meteorite

Comment: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js ?

Comment: So you want, basically, a new page to open when a record is clicked, showing the details of it? You just need to establish multiple templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the HTML

```
{{#if isList}}
   {{> listTemplate}}
{{/if}}

{{#if isDetail}}
   {{> detailTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

in the javascript on the client

```
Template.isList = function() {
   return Session.get("state") || Session.get("state") == "list"; 
}

Template.isDetail = function() {
   return Session.get("state") && Session.get("state") == "detail";
}

Template.listTemplate.events({
   "click #clickedRow" : function( event ) {
      Session.set("state", "detail")
   }
});

Template.detailTemplate.events({
   "click #backButton" : function( event ) {
      Session.set("state", "list")
   }
});
```

because Meteor will re-render your page when the `state` changes, the click on the items will have the effect of changing your page.